# .MP4 doesn't play fully

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

The code is simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <MediaElement x:Name="PerfectWMV" Grid.Row="1"
                   AutoPlay="True"
                   Source="/Assets/BenkyohPerfect.mp4"
    />
</Grid>
```

But the .MP4 doesn't play FULLY. It gets to approximately halfway then stops.
It's ten frames long and supposed to play for two seconds so I doubt it's a memory issue.
It plays halfway so I think the encoding is OK.

When I right-click the .MP4 in the VS Solution Explorer, it plays fine. Also plays fine in Media Player. I don't believe the file is damaged.

I used GSpot to try and check the .MP4 - I didn't see any red flags.

It goes to halfway regardless of which emulator I run in. I don't have a device [yet] so I can't tell if I have an emulator-only issue.

Any clues where to look next?

Comment: You've got only 5 frames per second in the file? Also, confirm the file is officially supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yes - only 5 frames per second in the file. And after reading the website ... I have no idea. Since I'm translating an animated .gif, maybe I should pick a different file format.